Perturbation Theory for Multivariate Polynomial System
I am looking for a general framework for carrying out perturbation expansions for polynomial systems in a similar way it is commonly done for univariate polynomials.
In particular, I have a problem of the form
$$
\varepsilon_1 = P_1(x,y,z),
$$
$$
\varepsilon_2 = P_2(x,y,z),
$$
$$
\varepsilon_3 = P_3(x,y,z).
$$
with $\varepsilon_i << 1$ and $P_i(x, y, z)$ are polynomials in three variables that do not depend on $\varepsilon_i$. The solutions of $P_i(x,y,z) = 0$ are known.
I am looking for a general procedure for writing $x, y, z$ as a powerseries in (fractional powers of) $\varepsilon_i$.
If this is infeasible in general, maybe a simpler problem, where the small parmeters are not completely independent, e.g. $\varepsilon_i = \alpha_i \varepsilon$ with $\alpha_i$ constants would be possible?
Is there any standard perturbation theory or algebraic geometry reference that treats problems of this type?

See this question on mathoverflow.
